# How in Setting List call from one list to another by fields in list

Tags: lookup-column, column

I know how call elements in the same list. It can be done by:
[image]

And then i take a copy from another list. Now a question how to colect a copy of field value, but from another list?

Answer (score 1):

Try below link and method,

1.Browse to the source list, click List tab on the ribbon bar and click List Settings icon.

2.Click “Save list as template” link that exists under Permission and Management section which will bring up another page where you need to provide template File Name, Template name and Template Description. Make sure you didn’t check “Include Content” checkbox. Then, click the OK button.

3.Go to Site Actions --> More options --> Click List under Filter By section. You can see the template which has been created in the previous step as part of other templates on the right pane. Choose the template and provide list name.

4.If there are any workflows associated with the existing list that may still persist on the newly created destination list. Usually when lists are saved as template, all workflows associated to the original list will be saved as part of template except currently running workflows. Make sure all workflows associated with the original list have been removed if it’s not required. To remove workflows associated to list, go to List Settings Click on Workflow Settings Click “Remove a workflow” link, choose Remove option and click OK button.

5.Open New (destination) List, Go to Site Actions --> Manage Content and Structure, choose the Original List on the left pane.

6.You can increase the currently showing items up to 1000, sort list items by clicking column header and choose all items by clicking Select All option (displyaed top-left corner on the header) or individual items can be selected by clicking the checkbox displayed on each individual item.

7.Click “Actions” --> Move and choose the target list (newly created destination list from template) on the popup.

8.Finally click the OK button and wait until the list items are moved to destination list. If required, follow step 5, 6 & 7 until you moved the required list items to destination list.

Saving a list as template (without content) will make sure the newly list has been created with original list schema and it also saves time for creating a new list manually. This approach requires admin privileges on the site which contains both source and destination lists.

Links:

1. http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-sharepoint-services-help/copying-or-moving-sharepoint-lists-HA001154562.aspx

Comment: I tried Your solution, but it coppy all elements from the list, but I can't do actualization. Should I only do workflow for it ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a lookup column. There's some details [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=574) (it's 2007, but hasn't changed)

Comment: But i don't want to choose one record. I want only put's value from one list to another list field. Copy one list to another, but with cant another users to edit a field.

Comment: I want to copy all values from one colum to another list with colum, but no choising them. Only copy like in my Question. Can I take a name of a list and then copy them ?

Comment: Does this describe what you want? http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/sharepoint-server-help/create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-HA101729901.aspx

Comment: Yes if I create new two list with new date, but what should I do when I have got one list with data, and want to create another one which containing a data from first list.